# Does VBA Have a Ternary Operator?

Tags: excel, vba

I come from the beautiful world of Obj C, which is based on the C programming language, and I've fallen in love with finding quirky ways to save space. However, I've looked through as much documentation as I can and I can't find anything juicy on VBA that will shorten this syntax:

```
If boolVar = True Then
   'Do something
Else
   'Do nothing
End If
```

In Obj C, and naturally C, I'm extremely familiar with doing this:

```
boolVar ? "Nope, tis false" : "Yup, tis true"
```

This is very similar to what most other languages use, some may use extra logical operators like `!=` or `==` but that leaves me optimistic. I may not have looked in the right places, if that's the case PLEASE **let me know** where you get your documentation.

TLDR, can we shorten If/Then/Else to one line of code in VBA? *This is extremely handy* when the 'Do Somethings' are nothing more then setting another variable's single parameter, or enabling/disabling a button.

Comment: [IIf()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264412(v=office.15).aspx)

Comment: VBA doesn't have a true ternary operator. There's the `IIf` *function*, but you add the overhead of a function call, giving you ***both*** decreased readability and performance.

Comment: Its also not short-circuited.

Comment: just to point out that `Iif()` function doesn't short-circuit and always evaluates both branches so that should one of them fail, even if not the "real" one, the statement would throw an error anyway

Comment: If you just want the decreased readability, simple expressions can use a single line `If..Else`:  `If boolVar = True Then x = "foo" Else x = "bar"`

Comment: ternary was on the tip of my tongue @Comintern glad you said it! that would have bothered me forever. I'm okay with decreased readability when it comes to simple tasks. can you elaborate on the performance hindrances? I just started to learn about VB

Comment: ahhhh @user3598756 that makes a big difference, and almost useless

Comment: You take a performance hit for any function call - pushing and popping the call stack, etc. I have no clue if objective C compiler inlines functions, but it's the opposite of that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @user3598756 i'll probably opt-out after you guys telling me it's not short-circuited. I'm okay with decreased readability as long as it doesn't return false positives, or in this case, false negatives, since one can always be true. Do you mind sharing as an answer? I would hate future question seekers miss that bit of info due to overlooking comment section

Comment: @Comintern I just read in the docs you don't have to use `End If` as a closer when the `If` & `Then` are on the same line! So I think that is sufficient. Gonna go with your example and opt out of `End If`

Comment: Just to clarify, `End If` isn't *optional* on a single line `If` statement, you can't have it *at all*.  ;-)

Comment: @soulshined; as per your request I added an answer

Comment: @Comintern I completely missed your example. You definetly didn't put it in there. I just skimmed it the first time. After I saw if then I gave up  your the man though! Or woman, I can't tell from here ;) thanks for not judging a newbie

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
Sub test()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    y = 1
    x = IIf(y = 1, 1, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: So you have to set a variable to the function first? Thats awkward. I was hoping it would be an 'out-of-box' experience. Thanks for the swift response. I'm going to have to look more into it based on the feedback in the comments above.

Comment: @soulshined You don't have to set a variable to a function; `IIF` is built into VBA. It works largely similarly to the ternary operator in C, however as others have pointed out it doesn't short-circuit and it is a function call. Here it is using your example: `IIF(boolVar, "Yup, tis true", "Nope, tis false" )`.

Comment: Yeah I realized that after testing @Blackhawk , too late to edit comment though :/

Answer (score 30):

the closest function is `IIf()`

```
IIf(expr, truepart, falsepart)
```

but:

- you can't have its branches simply running code, while you have to assign its return value to some variable,
- it doesn't short-circuit,

  it always evaluates both branches so that should one of them fail, even if not the "real" one, the statement would throw an error anyway.

So the most *resembling* statement is:

```
If boolVar Then sub1 Else sub2
```

where:

- `boolVar` is a boolean type variable,
- `sub1` and `sub2` are two different subs/functions to be called.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative you can create the following public function in a module:

```
Public Function iff(expr, trueR, falseR) As Variant
    If expr Then iff = trueR Else iff = falseR
End Function
```

So far works for me.

Comment: Your solution does not solve the issue of parameter resolution, i.e. if truer and falser are function calls then both functions will be called as part of the parameter resolution process and thus you will have the same problems as the standard IIf function.  For this reason a one line If then Else should be preferred.