# VBA assign value to variable conditionally

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to assign value conditionally to variable in one line?

```
Dim a as String
Dim b as String
a="hello world"

If a="hello world" Then b="Yes" Else b="No"
```

Is it possible to do the above code with a similar way to SQL syntax in one line - something like this:

```
b = Case When a="hello world" Then "Yes" Else "No" End
```

Comment: Look up the VBA functions  `IIF()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does VBA Have a Ternary Operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41596121/does-vba-have-a-ternary-operator)

Comment: You could write if a = "hello world" Then: b = "Yes": Else: b = "No"

Comment: @Storax wrong language :)

Comment: I do not think so, works fine for me. But I would agree, that's certainly not what the TO really wants :-)

Comment: @Storax The colons are superfluous. Simply  `If a = "hello world" Then b = "Yes" Else b = "No"` works.

Comment: Ah, thanks, now I got your point. Sorry!

Comment: The `If` statement in your first code does what you ask in one line of code, what is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the IIF Function.

```
dim a as string
dim b as string
a ="hello world"
b = IIF(a="hello world", "Yes", "No")
```

The format follows the basic Ternary format of question, true condition, false condition. The function can return objects as well as data types.

Comment: Did not you forget a b =  :-)

Comment: you are right, I forgot all about the b string equals. Thank you.